# Google DocumentAI -> ValueError: Protocol message Document has no "file" field

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

In my script, I have the following:

```
response = requests.get(list_url[0], allow_redirects=True)
s = io.BytesIO()
s.write(response.content)
s.seek(0)
mimetype="application/octet-stream"
document = {'file': s.read(), 'mime': mimetype}
request = {"name": name, "document": document}
```

However, when I send a request to the server:

```
result = client.process_document(request=request)
```

I get `ValueError: Protocol message Document has no "file" field`.

Is this due because google docAI doesn't accept octet-stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the latest version code of the document ai python client  `DocumentProcessorServiceClient` and found this function pass on its `request` field a `Process Request` object. You can check details of that function on the [process_document](https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai/blob/26039d5a3a6a0b410a66a42885040989329f08ae/google/cloud/documentai_v1/services/document_processor_service/client.py#L458) github code page.

[Process Request](https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai/blob/26039d5a3a6a0b410a66a42885040989329f08ae/google/cloud/documentai_v1/types/document_processor_service.py#L41) will accept either `inline_document` or a `raw_document` (both are mutual exclusive). Based on your code it looks like you are passing a [raw_document](https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai/blob/26039d5a3a6a0b410a66a42885040989329f08ae/google/cloud/documentai_v1/types/document_io.py#L32) which only accepts fields `content` and `mime_type` which should be used instead of `file` and `mime`.

If you check the [sample of using python library client for document ai](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library) you will find this lines which explain how it should be implemented:

```
...
    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "raw_document": document}

    result = client.process_document(request=request)
...
```

For additional details, you can check the official github project for [document ai](https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai/tree/26039d5a3a6a0b410a66a42885040989329f08ae) and the official google page for the [python client library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest).

Comment: Hello @An old man in the sea, were you able to address your issue?

Comment: Hi Betjens, yes I was, but by a round about way. Regardless, I decided to accept your answer. Thanks for the help. ;)